# "git merge" didn't merge deletion

Tags: git, merge, git-merge

A colleague has removed a file `Foo.qml` from branch `workbranch`. I did:

```
git checkout -b merge_workbranch
git merge workbranch
```

And noticed that the file `Foo.qml` is still present in the working copy, messing things up. Any ideas why this happened, and how to merge properly?

Comment: Was your local copy of the file modified at the time of checkout?

Comment: @CodeCaster: No, I had no local changes.

Comment: Is it in the `.gitignore`?

Comment: @CodeCaster: No.

Comment: Nice, so you found it. Did the file get created separately on both branches?

Comment: @CodeCaster: No, both branches were branched out from a single branch that contained this file.